# What are the options to import an external model into Stage3D?

Tags: flash, stage3d

From what I found out by a quick google lookup, the Stage3D support for model import is not the best.

Has anyone tried to do something like this and could provide me with some information on how to do it?

I'm interested in an importer capable of COLLADA/FBX or something along those lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [Away3d v4](http://away3d.com/).  It is a fairly complete solution for most 3D applications, and uses the Stage3D model for the latest version.

Comment: I found out Alternativa Platform, any thoughts on that one?

Comment: I have not used it, mainly because of the [license agreement](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/download8/).  It gives the right to use it, but not modify the code -- so you can't fix anything.  It also gives the right to revoke the license.  (I vaguely remember that the license was more restrictive in the past.) [Away3D license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) is Apache 2.0.